# What is the difference between the two words - Jagat and Vishva?

Tags: terminology, meaning, cosmology, words

The two words जगत (jagat) and विश्व  (vishva) are both Sanskrit in origin and are also used synonymously in common Hindi parlance.

In English, both translate to either 'world' or 'universe', or more uncommonly, 'existence.'

As per scripture, though, is there any difference in terms of spatial dimensions or other measures between the two words? Or are both words the same in Hindu cosmology?

Comment: Jagat means all movable entities in the universe. Vishva means everything whole world.

Comment: so ambit and scope of विश्व is bigger than जगत? जगत comes under विश्व ? @Adiyarkku

Comment: Yus correct……..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From dhatus - roots one can infer the basic meaning

> ज [ ja ] [ ja ]2 m. f. n. (√ [ jan ] ) ifc. born or descended from , produced or caused by , born or produced in or at or upon ,
> ग [ ga ] [ ga ]2 m. f. n. (√ [ gam ] )  going , moving
> *Monier*

Observable universe , a part of Jagat (infinite comos),comprises of all those that are born ,but eventually perish(goes away).  So jagat is transient(subjected to bhava , abhava). All that which undergoes bhava,abhava(presence,absence ) is Mithya.

Vish dhatu roop in Sanskrit means *to enter* (eg. word like grihapravesh can hold on to this basic meaning). According to Sri Shankara bhagavad pada commentary on Vishnu sahasranama, Universe has no seperate existence apart from Brahman.So Bhagavan is glorified as vishwam . (all pervading) .Brahman enters into effect (vishanti) after universe is Projected on creation. Upon dissolution, the universe(as avyakta - latent , blueprint) enters into Brahman . So Vishwam is ever existent, ( as manifest or unmanifest.)

Vishnu Sahasranama Sri Shankara Bhagavadpadas Commentary Translation Swami Tapasyananda RK mutt

[[image]]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

@[Adiyarkku](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/20129/adiyarkku) wrote in a [comment](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/55468/what-is-the-difference-between-the-two-words-jagat-and-vishva#comment169524_55468):

> *Jagat* means all movable entities in the universe. *Vishva* means everything whole world.

We can confirm this and add a few details/subtleties by looking at some interpretations of scripture.

Sāyaṇa, in his commentary on [Rig Veda 6.49.6](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/rig-veda-english-translation/d/doc834236.html), tells us that the usage of the word *jagat* in that line refers to non-fixed objects.

Meanwhile, Madhva, [in his commentary on the Mundaka Upanishad, writes](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/mundaka-upanishad-madhva-commentary/d/doc626511.html):

> The word *Viśvam* does also not just mean the “universe” here but the “Full”—the all-pervading in space, time and qualities.